# re-fill form values in jsp

Tags: forms, jsp

is it possible to redirect my jsp page to the same jsp page,with some form values filled in? like if I have first.jsp that contains a form, then I would want to redirect it back to first.jsp with a few buttons enabled and the form values should be filled automatically this time. I know how to enable the buttons, it's just the refilling of form that's troubling me. Or even if I had to redirect to another jsp, say second.jsp,but how do I retain the form values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and easily doable with JSTL. Look at my answer here [How to re-populate form fields on a jsp page after failed server validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966087/how-to-re-populate-form-fields-on-a-jsp-page-after-failed-server-validation/5966160#5966160)

You can just do `<input name="foo" type="text" value="${param.foo}"/>`

Comment: <c:out value="${param.foo}"/>

Comment: `fn:escapeXml()` is IDE and JSPX friendlier. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java

Answer (score -1):

have you considered using spring binding?